# Nhibernate Interceptor - Get Property length OnSave

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have simple NHibernate interceptor and override method OnSave().

Now what I am trying to do here is to get SQL length for string properties.
Is that possible.

I can see that property `IType[]` types contains `SqlType` where `Length` is available, but just cannot find how to read it. Example from debug:

[image]

This is example of the code which I have, and where I am trying to get Sql length of property.

```
public override bool OnSave(object entity, object id, object[] state, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.Length; i++)
    {
        //If type is string
        if (types[i].GetType() == typeof(NHibernate.Type.StringType))
        {
             //Get SQL length of string property   
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any help how I can get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just try to cast the `IType` into intended one:

```
//If type is string
var stringType = types[i] as NHibernate.Type.StringType;

//if (types[i].GetType() == typeof(NHibernate.Type.StringType))
if(stringType != null)
{
     //Get SQL length of string property   
     var length = stringType.SqlType.Length;
}
```